# Error importing Google Cloud python library in Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure

I have Python code that I used to develop an Azure Function App, and the code involves me importing the `google-cloud-bigquery` library. I have a list of requirements.txt in the project folder with the libraries mentioned. Now I have tried importing it, in both the following ways:

```
import google.cloud.bigquery
import google.oauth2.service_account
```

and

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
```

but I get an error:

> Exception while executing function: Functions.test_function <---
>   Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'google.cloud' Stack: File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py",
>   line 239, in _handle__function_load_request

Can someone tell me how to use external Python libraries in Azure Functions (Dynamic-Consumption Plan on a Linux machine) ?

**requirements.txt** looks like this:

```
google-cloud-bigquery
google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]
pandas-gbq
azure
azure-cosmos
```

Comment: Can you share your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Adding it to the main questions now :)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce, after installing those requirements I can run `from google.cloud import bigquery` successfully. Can you double-check that the filename of `requirements.txt` is correct? You also probably don't need both `google-cloud-bigquery` and `google-cloud-bigquery[pandas]`, as the latter will replace the former.

Comment: Your `requirements.txt` is missing several modules. Use `virtualdev` and recreate your runtime environment. Then do a `pip freeze` and use that for your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Ca you specify more ? I have run this on a Jupyter Notebook and it works fine.

Comment: I ran a `pip freeze` and printed the hard list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Azure Functions are primarily for serverless compute. Installing Python libraries permanently is not supported.